# How to use for loop to plot data from files using Gnuplot with C++?

Tags: c++, gnuplot

I am using Gnuplot with C++ to display data from a .dat file that is modified in a for loop.

Despite I use `fflush` at each loop to send the input commands to Gnuplot, eventually these commands are executed all at once when the for loop terminates and the Gnuplot pipe is closed.

To better explain the problem, I wrote a simple program which displays the multiplication tables from 1 to 10. Each table is stored in  “multiplicationTable.dat” and the command `"plot \"multiplicationTable.dat\" using 1:2 w l lw 2 lc rgb 'blue'\n";` is sent to Gnuplot with `fprintf`.

However, instead of generating a different png file for each multiplication table, this program generates ten identical figures, all corresponding to the 10th multiplication table. How can I force `"plot \"multiplicationTable.dat\" using 1:2 w l lw 2 lc rgb 'blue'\n";` to be executed in any loop? I thought `fflush` did the job but apparently I am missing something.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <direct.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{   
    // Call gnuplot
    FILE* gnuplotPipe = popen("\"C:\\Program Files\\gnuplot\\bin\\gnuplot\" -persist","w");

    char* cwd = _getcwd( 0, 0 ); // Store current working directory into string 
    string stringCwd(cwd);

    ofstream outFile; // to store the multiplication tables
    string gnuplotCommands; 

    for(int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
    {
        // Define gnuplot commands
        stringstream figureNumber;
        figureNumber << i; 
        gnuplotCommands = "reset\n"
                          "cd '" + stringCwd + "'\n"
                          "set terminal png size 1920,1080\n"
                          "set output 'Figure" + figureNumber.str() + ".png'\n"
                          "set size 0.5,0.5\n"
                          "set origin 0.25,0.25\n"
                          "plot \"multiplicationTable.dat\" using 1:2 w l lw 2 lc rgb 'blue'\n";

        // Store multiplication table [i*1, i*2, ..., i*10] into .dat file
        outFile.open("multiplicationTable.dat",ios::out);                 
        for(int j = 1; j <= 10; j++)
            outFile << j << " " << i*j << endl; 
        outFile.close();

        // Write gnuplot commands
        fprintf(gnuplotPipe,gnuplotCommands.c_str());
        fflush(gnuplotPipe); //flush pipe 

    }

    fprintf(gnuplotPipe,"exit \n");   // exit gnuplot
    pclose(gnuplotPipe);    //close pipe

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: fflush() does do the job. But your program doesn't wait for gnuplot to complete execution of the commands, it plows ahead and completes its own loop 10 times before gnuplot has time to read the data file.  You need to synchronize the two programs somehow at the end of each loop. How best to do that depends on your larger task flow and environment.

Comment: Thank you @EthanMerritt for your answer. I followed your tip by adding command Sleep(1000) to pause the code for 1 second at the end of each iteration and now the code is working correctly. Would it be possible to further improve the code by generating the png files without storing the data in a separate file? Indeed, the current approach requires the file to be opened, rewritten and closed at each iteration and this can be cumbersome.

Comment: Sure.  You could write the data in-line and have gnuplot read the data from the same input stream as the commands.  That should work.